# ubuntuphone does not sync radicale calendar anymore since OTA-13

Tags: sync, calendar

I've created a custom script to sync my radicale calendars with my phone that I launch manually in the terminal. It was working fine till the last system upgrade OTA-13. Now it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] error code from SyncEvolution error parsing config file (local,
status 20010): backend not supported by any of the backend modules
(syncxmlrpc, syncsqlite, syncqtcontacts, syncmaemocal, synckcalextended,
syncfile, syncecal, syncebook, syncdav, syncactivesync, provideruoa,
platformgnome) or not correctly configured (backend=select backend
databaseFormat= syncFormat=)
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Here you have the different steps I did to have my script working:

```
echo "Instruct on how to reach the calendar server"

syncevolution --configure --template webdav syncURL="http://myCaldavSerUrl/" target-config@radicale

echo "  create calendars on the phone"

syncevolution --create-database backend=evolution-calendar database=myCalendar

echo "instruct about remote databases"

syncevolution --configure database=http://myCaldavSerUrl/myCalendar/mycalendar.ics/ backend=caldav target-config@radicale myCalendar

echo " connect remote calendars"

syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client sync=none syncURL=local://@radicale username= myusr password= mypass

echo " Add calendars "

syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=evolution-calendar database=myCalendar radicale myCalendar

echo "  First synchro between server and phone"

syncevolution --sync refresh-from-remote radicale myCalendar

echo "  Regular synchro script"

syncevolution radicale myCalendar
```

Comment: Did you previously remount the `/` partition as `rw` in order to install another package?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i do not understand what you mean. To make my question more clear, I've added the different scripts used to create and synchronize my calendar. This was working fine till the last upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I just had to delete all the calendars databases on my ubuntuphone, recreate them as I did in the beginning and relaunch synchronisation. The script works again. I don't know what happened exactly during the last upgrade, but rebuilding my databases corrected the problem.

If this can help someone else.

Thanks to all the people contributing to the ubuntuphone!
Ciao

Jean Pierre